# jscript dropdown menu doesn't work on other buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

im creating a navigation bar using button with dropmenu. but only one button functions well (Abou us button). clicking other button (Blog)  displays the same dropmenu though i put different   menu for it. here's my code. thank you for help.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event){
    if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')){
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;

        for(i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++){
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if(openDropdown.classList.contains('show')){
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"> About us <img src="images/whitearrow.png" width="10" height="10" ></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="site_profile.php">Company Profile</a>
        <a href="Management.php">Management</a>
        <a href="testimonials.php">Testimonials</a>
        <a href="services.php">Services </a>
    </div>
</div>      

<div class="dropdown">  
    <span><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" >Blog <img src="images/whitearrow.png" width="10" height="10" ></button></span>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Tips</a>
        <a href="#">Success Story</a>
        <a href="#">Featured Employee</a>
        <a href="#">Events </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can create a jsFiddle as an example?

Comment: jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/c1d5oge6/

Comment: You have given both drop-downs the same id "myDropdown". ids should be unique. When you run myFunction() it gets the element by this non-unique id therefore it gets the first one whichever button you click on.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/jsfiddle-an-online-playground-for-your-javascript-html-css/

Comment: thanks. :) it works. i created another function and  id. another problem is that when i clicked the other menu, the previous dropmenu is still open. how can i hide it when i clicked another menu? thank you in advance :*